# Disable a built-in microphone and webcam remotely

Tags: windows-10, powershell, remote-control, wmi

We have some laptops docked at certain places that my head people want disabled. I have used `Get-WMIObject` to pull the class `Win32_PnpEntity` and used the Devcon utility to disable the "internal microphone" remotely, but the microphone still is working even though the driver is disabled.

Besides physically disabling them is there a way that I can disable these items remotely?

Comment: Did you restart the remote machine after changes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it. I had the user check, but now I wonder if it is only applying to my profile. I was ran the commands while being psremoted into the machine.